# How can I set for this apk to be uploaded on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

> Upload failed
>   You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs or Android App Bundles.
>
> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. Learn more about signing.
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 6D:2A:A3:6C:37:0D:8B:61:56:DB:A7:07:98:A8:C6:C7:28:26:54:04 ]
>   and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 51:23:93:B4:A0:84:93:FD:4B:EF:78:C4:C8:1A:0A:BE:96:FA:F1:D1 ]
>
> Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.vukaboda.app.
>
> You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.

What do I have do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` version for your `android` module, you will have `debuggable true` in one of your build types.

To release an APK on the store you cannot build a build type with this enabled.

**EDIT** It looks as though your have built the wrong build type and tried to upload it as an update to an already existing app on the store. In which case

- The package name must be `com.vukaboda.app`. Normally set in your app module's `build.gradle` file.
- The signing certificate must be the same. This is the keystore you use to generate your release APK where you enter your keystore alias, alias password and keystore password.
- The version code must be at least 1 higher than the highest version of your app uploaded to the play console (this includes unreleased versions).

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : generate **signed apk** of your application

step 2 : you have already upload old version of your application into playstore then **change the version code**.

step 3 : use same **old SHA signature** of your application as you have been created when generate by **you in past** because you have already uploaded same application into playstore so both **new and old apk required same signature** while generating new signed apk ;)

Comment: Thanks for the views ! You know what the old app was developed using some softwate which is note android studuio, (APK Builder Pro 3.0.2) . Now we have i have developed using android studio what can i do then ?? apart from the previous question?